# Move application to another desktop directly

Tags: desktop, applications

When I open my application on **desktop 1**. I can't open it in **desktop 2**, it will jump back to **desktop 1**.

Can I directly move the application to desktop 2 without exiting the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On desktop 1, open the Mission Control (four fingers, swipe up), you will see desktop spaces on top of the screen.  Move the application to desktop 2.

Or, on desktop 1, drag the application, move it to the right edge of the screen, wait two second, the desktop will be switch to desktop 2, and your application will be there.

Answer (score 2):

Another way: you can press mouse button on window's border and then press `Ctrl + →` (default) to move selected window (without releasing mouse button).